# Postcondition for a segment of code

Tags: java

A question in the Barron's APCS book asks to consider the following program segment:

```
// Precondition: a[0]...a[n-1] is an initialized array of integers, and 0 < n <= a.length.

int c = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (a[i] >= 0) {
        a[c] = a[i];
        c++;
    }
}
n = c;
```

Given the segment, I am supposed to choose the best postcondition for the segment. The postconditions given are:

```
A) a[0]...a[n-1] has been stripped of all positive integers. 

B) a[0]...a[n-1] has been stripped of all negative integers. 

D) a[0]...a[n-1] has been stripped of all nonnegative integers. 

C) a[0]...a[n-1] has been stripped of all occurrences of zero.

E) The updated value of n is less than or equal to the value of n before execution of the segment.
```

The book says the correct answer is B. Why is that? If array `a` were to contain only negative integers, the value of n at the end of the segment would be 0, and a[0]...a[n-1] would then be a[0]...a[-1].

Comment: `a[0]...a[-1]` is just an empty array (and so it's not incorrect to say that all negative integers have been removed from it). I think your book's answer is fine.

Comment: Assuming n=a.length before the execution of the segment, B is correct and E is correct. Choosing either will satisfy a postcondition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer of the book is wrong.

The correct answer is E.

Suppose n = 5, and you have 5 values a[i = 0, 4] = {-1, -2, -3, 4, 5}

After execution the value of a[i] are: {4, 5, -3, 4, 5}

And n = c = 2

The function read: Loop through the list, if a non-negative int found (n >= 0) then update the beginner of array with a copy value of it.

Hence `c = non-negative int count`

From this observation, you can choose the correct answer then.

Comment: I still don't get it (probably a notational issue). Would you mind spelling out how option B is incorrect in your example? Thanks!

Comment: oops, we still have a = -3 left after execution? I think you're stressed on the part value `n` is updated after execution. The option B is correct if and only if they reference the value of updated `n` (like option E)

Comment: Definitely a notational issue then. (My interpretation is that `n` in the postcondition references the updated value of `n`, just as it would do in real code.) P.S. Am not familiar with the book or the notation used there.

Comment: Ya but option E stressed on the `updated` part. And if B is correct then option D is also correct, right? So it leads to contradiction

Comment: Well, option E necessarily has to disambiguate since it looks at `n` both before and after. And I don't see how option D is correct (the `{4, ...}` in your answer is a counterexample).

Comment: I must drunk when write that comment haha.